# How to simple responsive CSS-Grid (columns) adjusted to the parent container?

Tags: html, css-grid

Greetz together!

I'm trying to use CSS-Grid for a simple Carousel/Slider component. Can someone explain me how to breakdown the columns each breakpoint?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4cnp0kb6/120/

```js
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#carouse_next');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#track').style.transform = 'translateX(calc(-100% - 16px))';
});

const prevButton = document.querySelector('#carouse_prev');

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#track').style.transform = 'translateX(0%)';
});
```

```css
body {
     padding: 0 1rem;
     margin: 0;
}
 .grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/2);
     width: 100%;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
     grid-auto-flow: column;
     grid-gap: 0 16px;
}
 .grid > * {
     background: lightcoral;
     height: 200px;
     grid-column-start: span 2;
}
 .carousel {
     background: purple;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .carousel .control {
     position: relative;
}
 .carousel .track {
     display: flex;
     transform: translateX(0%);
     width: 100%;
     will-change: transform;
     transition: transform 1s;
}
 .carousel .track .view {
     flex: 1 0 100%;
     margin-right: 16px;
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 560px) {
     .carousel .grid {
         grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/4);
         grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 2fr);
    }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
     .carousel .grid {
         grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/5);
         grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 2fr);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="control">
     <div class="track" id="track">

      <div class="view">
        <div class="grid">
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="view">
        <div class="grid">
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
        </div>
      </div>      

    </div> 
 
  </div>
</div>

<button id="carouse_prev">
Prev
</button>

<button id="carouse_next">
Next
</button>
```

**The Goal**
Columns width should fit into the parent `.view` wrapper:

Large: 5 cols
Medium: 4 cols
Small: 2 cols

If the user is on medium-breakpoint the last column should swap to the next view (parent accepts overflow) similar like this:\

```js
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#carouse_next');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#track').style.transform = 'translateX(calc(-100% - 16px))';
});

const prevButton = document.querySelector('#carouse_prev');

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#track').style.transform = 'translateX(0%)';
});
```

```css
body {
     padding: 0 1rem;
     margin: 0;
}
 .grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/2 - 16px);
     width: 100%;
     grid-auto-flow: column;
     grid-gap: 0 16px;
}
 .grid > * {
     background: lightcoral;
     height: 200px;
}
 .carousel {
     background: purple;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .carousel .control {
     position: relative;
}
 .carousel .track {
     display: flex;
     transform: translateX(0%);
     width: 100%;
     will-change: transform;
     transition: transform 1s;
}
 .carousel .track .view {
     flex: 1 0 100%;
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 560px) {
     .carousel .grid {
         grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/4 - 16px);
    }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
     .carousel .grid {
         grid-auto-columns: calc(100%/5 - 16px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="control">
     <div class="track" id="track">

      <div class="view">
        <div class="grid">
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
          <div>column1</div>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="view">
        <div class="grid">
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
          <div>column2</div>
        </div>
      </div>      

    </div> 
 
  </div>
</div>

<button id="carouse_prev">
Prev
</button>

<button id="carouse_next">
Next
</button>
```

But here i'm fighting always with the grid-gap. If remove this property and consider it on `calc()` too, it will work but i need the grid-gap to keep other components above/below the carousel on same look.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. Use the Stack Snippet feature.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin i think jsfiddle is good too

Comment: Added your wishes